Apple hardware modules in directory other than that used by Linux kernel for startup modules
I recently installed Linux on a 2019 MacbookPro and do not have the ability to use the laptop trackpad or keyboard, nor to connect to a WiFi network.
I am wondering, is my path to the startup modules wrong, or are my apple modules in the wrong place? Or should they all be together in the same directory, which does not currently appear to be the base, meaning that something probably went wrong during Linux installation?
I followed the steps in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800731/module-not-found-when-i-do-a-modprobe?newreg=faffad4c0f17445fb7d4ef9587c6e5fe when I do a modprobe but cannot load the apple module/s. I found that they were already installed, but the directory used for startup/kernel modules appears to be different from the directory being used by the kernel to actually load modules.
The modules are in /urs/src/, whereas the path to the directory currently being used for startup modules appears to be /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic
I assume this is the case as the error I receive when attempting modprobe apple_bce is: modprobe: FATAL: Module applce_bce not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic.
